# How can redirect to confirmation page with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I am working on a form with nextjs13, chakra-ui, react-hook-form.

There's a text input field where user put email address.
(url is `xxx/new`)

here's form I have:

```
export const NewForm = () => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        trigger,
        watch,
    } = useForm<NewFormType>();

   
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
        //do something
        console.log(data);
    });

    return (
        <Box>
            <Box>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>                      
                  <FormControl isInvalid={!!errors[`email`]}>
                     <Input
                       id={"email"}
                       type={"email"}
                       {...register("email", {
                                    required: "required",   
                       })}
                     />
                   </FormControl>
                </form>
                <Box>
                    <Button>Confirm</Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

When user hits 'Confirm' button, I want to move to the confirmation page with url `xxx/confirm` and show whatever user put.

I know that I can show/hide confirm component using state variable if the form and confirmation component on the same page but not sure when they are not on the same page.
(also, I cannot use query parameter)

Is there any hook I can use? or should I use Provider in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use useRouter Hook to redirect to the confirm page and React context to pass data between component. You just need to create context and then store it's value inside the onSubmit handler like shown below

```
const { setFormData } = useConfirmationContext();

const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
    // set the form data in the context
    setFormData(data);
    // navigate to the confirmation page
    router.push(`xxx/confirm`);
});
```

and then you can get the data in the confirmation page like below

```
const { formData } = useConfirmationContext();
```

Please try this way and update.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to share states through multiple components like context api or other state management libraries and etc.

In my opinion if you're already using react-hook-form, you'd better use built-in 'useFormContext' hook of react-hook-form.

https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/

Also, If you'd like to navigate page to page in next.js, you might have to use router from 'next/navigation'.

maybe like this,

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const router = useRouter();

...
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
        router.push(`xxx/confirm`)
    });
...
```

```
// some page
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

...
const { getValues, watch } = useFormContext();
// you can use getValues or watch to read form values.
...
```

Comment: To use useFormContext to get the shared value, shouldn't the confirmation component and form component be within the same FormProvider? Since confirmation and form page are in two different pages (ie. different url), I thought that I can't use useFormContext in this scenario. Am I wrong?

Comment: @amu03 You also have to wrap your pages with context provider even if you use context api to make consuming components get rerendered. Afaik, useformcontext is built based on context api, so I think you'd better use this hook if there's no other form context in confirmation page.